# How to stop the screen from re-rendering onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, react-component

I have a page consist of a dropdown and a Chart, the dropdown receives items from the server, whenever the user select something from the dropdown which triggers the handleSelectionChange() event that updates the current selection in local state, the entire MetricList() gets executed again,

In the code below, the "console.log("TESTING") will continue to log every time I make a dropdown selection.

What should I do so when I select something in the dropdown, it only changes the local state?

````
const MetricList = () => {
  ///get the list of metrics for dropdown
  FetchMetricList(); 

  //get dropdown data from the redux store.
  const { getMetrics } = useSelector(getMetric);

  //craete local state called metricSelected
  const [metricSelected, setGreeting] = useState([]);

  //loading spinner if no data arrives
  if (!getMetrics) return <CircularProgress />;

  //create dropdown data using Data from getMetrics
  let data = [];
    getMetrics.forEach(value => {
      let obj = { key: value, text: value, value: value };
      data.push(obj);
    });

  // FOR TESTING PURPOSE
  console.log("TESTING")

  //when user make selection in dropdown, update local state
  const handleSelectionChange = (event, { value }) => {
    setGreeting( [value] );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select..."
        fluid
        multiple
        selection
        data={data}
        style={{ width: "500px" }}
        onChange={handleSelectionChange}
      />
      <Charts
        dataSelected={metricsSelected}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is how react works.  If the state in your component changes it will re-render that component.  Right now every time the state in your `MetricList` component changes the `MetricList` component will re-render.

Is what you want for something in your component to only be executed on the initial render?

If that's the case you need to use something like the `useEffect` hook and only render it on initial render or use a class based component and run it in `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillMount()`.

So for example if you only want the `FetchMetricList()` to run once on the initial render you can do something like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  FetchMetricList()
}, []);
```

or in a class based component you can call it like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
  FetchMetricList();
}
```

otherwise it is going to run on every render like is happening now.  Not sure if that is the function you don't want running at every render but it is just an example.  But that is the nature of using a state based component system.  Every time the components state changes that component is re-rendered.

Hopefully I understood what you were wanting.  I was a little confused by your question because the description of what you problem was (the re-rendering of a component on state change) is the basic functionality of how react works.  If I misunderstood then please let me know in the comments below.